# Python. Объединение четырех строк в одну

Tags: строки

Как можно несколько строк (3) преобразовать в одну? Есть вот такой случай. Программа выводит все числа меньше 10, которые кратны 3 или 5. **Но нужно вывести сумму цифр.** 
Вот, как я пытался это сделать: преобразовать числа в строки, ( числа 3, 5, 6 и 9 ), но они все выводятся разными строками, друг под другом. 
Я думаю, что нужно преобразовать все это в одну строку, а строку в список и там уже обратно в числа и посчитать сумму, если так можно...
Мой код:

```
n = 0
sum = 0

for i in range (1, 9 + 1):
        n = n + 1
        if n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0:
            print(n)
            l = str(n)
            print(list(l))


input()
```

Comment: Вот в чем дело... Сразу у меня не  получается что-то просто сложить их...

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто сразу считать сумму и все.

```
for n in range (1, 9 + 1):
    if n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0:
        sum = sum + n
print(sum)
```

Comment: Спасибо) Что-то я затупил. Я делал так: sum = n + n...